# Java NullPointerException when calling listFiles() on a directory

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a series of folders containing books on a server which I am accessing with this piece of code. I want to make each of these folders an object so I can do some work with the files inside them later on. I'm trying to use this method to return a list of the folders as Book objects.

```
public List<Book> getBooks(File folder){
    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
    for (File f : folder.listFiles()){
        if (f.isDirectory()){
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath() + "" + f.listFiles());
            books.add(new Book(f));
        }
    }
    return books;
}
```

The println statement in this block is printing, as it should, the direct path to the folder and then the memory address along with some other information. However, somewhere in the folder it is printing out null when listFiles() is called. The folder that it is doing this on is not empty. This supposedly empty folder is then passed to my class init method.

```
public Book(File bookFolder) {
    this.bookFolder = bookFolder;
    this.bookPath = bookFolder.getAbsolutePath();

    System.out.println(bookFolder + " " + bookFolder.listFiles());

    for (File f : bookFolder.listFiles()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The println statement in this block prints out the exact same path to the folder and then a different memory address, which is also expected. When it hits the "empty" folder it prints null for the memory address again.

Now, for the real issue, the line with the for loop is where the program crashes and throws a NullPointerException which isn't even described in the documentation for the listFiles method.

Why could this be happening? Also, why are my non-empty folders returning null?

Comment: Stack traces are there for a reason. Read it, understand it.

Comment: @Mat - the 'foreach' operator (`:`) throws an NPE if the object to be iterated over is null (in your case, `bookFolder.listFiles()`)

Comment: @skaffman - stacktrace only tells you where an NPE occurs, not why.  Sometimes it's obvious, sometimes not, depending on how much is going on with that line.

Comment: @Kevin K - thanks, that was the answer I was looking for. Now I just have to figure out why they are null in the first place.

Comment: As a side note, your variable names are confusing. A `book` is a `File` and to add it to the list of `books`, you must create a `Book` from a `book`. I'd suggest not confusing books with files.

Comment: How you can iterate over a File in `for (File f : folder){` ?

Comment: Hi Mat, I saw your comment in one of the answer said listFiles could possibly return null if there are too many open files? Is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 30):

The documentation for the [`listFiles()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) method clearly states that it "Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs."

One of the most common reasons that a directory cannot be listed is that the process lacks the right permissions. Are you running this as yourself, or in some sort of service that runs as a different user?

By the way, the `File` API is a great example of how bad life can be without exceptions.

Comment: Another reason can be that the File isn't a directory.

Comment: Well, that's certainly true in general! But, in this case, it looks like the appropriate testing is done to rule that out.

Comment: @erickson I wanted to know why they are returning null when I'm certain they contain other files. The path is definitely a directory since I check to make sure it is and the other folders on the same server work fine with this code so I don't think it is a problem with permissions.

Comment: This code is run with a service that runs it as the admin user which makes me even more certain that it isn't a permissions issue.

Comment: @Mat - login as that user and list the directory yourself, just to make sure. Even if it works, you might see some clue as to why this directory is treated differently from the others.

Comment: @erickson - Thank you very much for your help. As is turns out I seem to be running out of space because I am opening so many files, this seems to be why listFiles() starts to return null instead of memory addresses.

Answer (score 4):

For developers who have already included the following solutions :

1. Added the storage permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

2.The directory from you want to list the files exists.

3. Enabled the permission in the device you are testing in the app permission settings

**BELOW CODE WILL SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM IF YOUR DEVICE SDK IS GREATER THAN OR EQUALS TO ANDROID 10(Q)**

*In the manifest file include this code inside  tag*

```
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"...</application>
```

Let me know if your problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with dir.listfiles(); returning null for the user folder \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\

it was the folder had by default Permissions set on "everyone" Deny all

what screwed me over i think was the fact that I never expected any Deny permission to exist there.

also for any one thats unclear on what i mean by a deny permission

when you set deny for user permissions it overrides the allow for user permissions unless you remove it and it was on a default install of windows 10 home.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was caused by trailing spaces. Use variable.trim()